# Error in plot.new(): figure margins too large, pairs() command

Tags: r

I have a dataframe which contains 23 continuous variables. Before I start analyzing the data, I want to check for correlations.

I usually do this by the `pairs()` function, like this:

```
pairs(mydata, lower.panel = panel.smooth2, 
      upper.panel = panel.cor, diag.panel = panel.hist)
```

Of course, I have specified the panels beforehand with a function.

Now when I want to do this with my data containing 23 variables, thus producing a 23 x 23 matrix of plots, I get the following error:

> Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large

It looks like I have to adjust my plot size or something. How do I do this?

Comment: Any common computer screen will be worthless in display this kind of image from the default device. Have you tried plotting to a file?

Comment: try `x11()` to plot to a new window. works sometimes.

Comment: Nit: your data are *not* continuous by definition.

Comment: Hi all, thank you for the replies.
Eventually I fixed it in a very simple way. I work in RStudio and this problem can be avoided simply by enlarging the graph window in your RStudio program.

Comment: So its good to know that enlarging the graph window can solve this problem, but how about a generalized solution? i have for instance 54 features and i'm running into the same problem, enlarging the graph window did not solve the problem. Also, using a device did not work: ```pdf("pairs.pdf")
pairs(DT)
dev.off()```

Comment: This is really a specific case of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12766166/error-in-plot-new-figure-margins-too-large-in-r, but the answer is the same: enlarge your plotting device or reduce the margins. With 23 variables it is unlikely your plot will be readable anyway.