# Histogram, error: Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large

Tags: r, histogram, par

I have to plot 141 histograms in R. I am working with windows 8. then I write:

```
par(mfcol=c(12,12), oma=c(1,1,0,0))

for(m in 1:141 ){
  x <- precData[[m]]
  hist(x[x != 0],30, xlab=NA, ylab=NA, main=statData$Name[m])
}
```

But always I get this error: Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large

How can I solve it??
Is there any command for adjusting the size of each histogram??

Thanks.

Comment: Any of these help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12766166/error-in-plot-new-figure-margins-too-large-in-r

Comment: Do you happen to be using RStudio?

Comment: No, it does not help me...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You set the outer margins (outside the whole set of plots) but the inner margins (for each panel) are at the default.  With the margins at the default, there is not enough room within each panel to plot the histogram and have the marginal information.

So you need to change the inner margins as well, and if you want anything to look reasonable then you should also change size and position of the things to be added.

Here is an example (I had to change to random data since your example was not reproducible):

```
par(mfcol=c(12,12), oma=c(1,1,0,0), mar=c(1,1,1,0), tcl=-0.1, mgp=c(0,0,0))

for(m in 1:141 ){
  x <- rnorm(100)
  hist(x[x != 0],30, xlab=NA, ylab=NA, main=paste('data: ',m), 
        cex.axis=0.5, font.main=1, cex.main=0.8)
}
```

Answer (score 13):

If it occurs using RStudio, you could try to enlarge your plot window. Sometimes it helps.

Comment: Yeah, I tried to enlarge it, but it doesnt help, because it is many histograms: 141 hists.

Comment: That's what I was going to suggest. I had the same problem a few weeks ago and the solution for me was to enlarge the plot window.

Comment: Keep resizing plot window is annoying.
Is there any one who knows a better way?