# Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large, Scatter plot

Tags: r, plot, figure, margins

I've looked in different questions for a solution and I've tried what was suggested but I have not found a solution to make it work.

Everytime I want to run this code it always says:

> Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large

and I don't know how to fix it. Here is my code:

```
par(mfcol=c(5,3))
hist(RtBio, main="Histograma de Bio Pappel")
boxplot(RtBio, main="Diagrama de Caja de Bio Pappel")
stem(RtBio)
plot(RtBio, main="Gráfica de Dispersión")

hist(RtAlsea, main="Histograma de Alsea")
boxplot(Alsea, main="Diagrama de caja de Alsea")
stem(RtAlsea)
plot(RtTelev, main="Gráfica de distribución de Alsea")

hist(RtTelev, main="Histograma de Televisa")
boxplot(telev, main="Diagrama de Caja de Televisa")
stem(Telev)
plot(Telev, main="Gráfica de dispersión de Televisa")

hist(RtWalmex, main="Histograma de Walmex")
boxplot(RtWalmex, main="Diagrama de caja de Walmex")
stem(RtWalmex)
plot(RtWalmex, main="Gráfica de dispersión de Walmex")

hist(RtIca, main="Histograma de Ica")
boxplot(RtIca, main="Gráfica de caja de Ica")
stem(RtIca)
plot(RtIca, main="Gráfica de dispersión de Ica")
```

What can I do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12766166/error-in-plot-new-figure-margins-too-large-in-r)

Comment: Margins appear to be too large for your image. This can happen if you have a small plot window. In any case, your description is insufficient to diagnose the problem. We could use a reproducible example or screenshot of your R session with the plot window.

Comment: I my case, it helped to debug with a small subset of the data that was to be plotted like `plot(df[1,1:3], df2[1,1:3])` - and then I realized that what I actually wanted to do is to `plot(unlist(df[1,1:3]), unlist(df2[1,1:3]))` Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17074060/6018688

Answer (score 236):

Every time you are creating plots you might get this error - "`Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large`". To avoid such errors you can first check `par("mar")` output. You should be getting:

```
[1] 5.1 4.1 4.1 2.1
```

To change that write:

```
par(mar=c(1,1,1,1))
```

This should rectify the error. Or else you can change the values accordingly.

Hope this works for you.

Comment: how do you exactly know which values are inside the margins? And why do you say that I should be getting [1] 5.1 4.1 4.1 2.1 but then you tell me to chage it to all 1's?

Comment: I ran into the same problem with RStudio, and when I entered `par("mar")` I retrieved the same exact string `[1] 5.1 4.1 4.1 2.1` so I entered `par(mar=c(1,1,1,1))` but then plot() would not plot anything, so I had to close close both RStudio and the terminal. After reopening RStudio, it was back to normal.

Comment: Running into the same problem in R markdown in RStudio as well. Neither Guest R's solution or @noobninja restart fixed it for me though.

Comment: You are getting this error because of an RStudio UI layout issue, not something wrong with the code. The second answer fixed it for me.

Comment: @Nicole Sullivan I got this error also without RStudio. I did as described and it works. Thanks @djhurio!

Comment: This solution did not work for me.  The next solution below (dev.off()) did work for me.

Comment: This worked for me with `par(mar=c(2,2,2,2))`. To answer @HermanToothrot, It seems those are the default values, which is how he knows what you should get, and then he decreases them all to 1.

Answer (score 157):

This can happen when your plot panel in RStudio is too small for the margins of the plot you are trying to create. Try making expanding it and then run your code again.

RStudio UI causes an error when the plot panel is too small to display the chart:
[image: RStudio with the plot panel too small]

Simply expanding the plot panel fixes the bug and displays the chart:
[image: RStudio with the plot panel expanded]

Comment: It indeed works.. simply expanding the plot area helps

Comment: Yes, resizing the panels in RStudio works. It is an RStudio bug caused when you minimize the right side of the UI by sliding the plot panel shut.

Comment: this actually works in the majority of cases. there is a small minority of cases where the margins are indeed so small that even if you maximize this window you have no solution to this problem

Comment: I first tried this, to no avail. Then I tried to set `par(mar=c(1,1,1,1))`, as suggested in another answer, and it worked. No idea why. :(

Comment: This should have been answer number one

Answer (score 40):

Invoking `dev.off()` to make RStudio open up a new graphics device with default settings worked for me. HTH.

Comment: Could you please explain how to do that?

Comment: Type `dev.off()` in the R console, hit Enter.

Comment: I ran into that error with an @example when building a package. Adding dev.off() in the example solved the problem. Thx. :-)

Comment: But if your are making more than one figure, try to add this as well:
par(mar=rep(2, 4))

Answer (score 20):

If you get this message in RStudio, clicking the 'broomstick' figure "Clear All Plots" in Plots tab and try plot() again.

Moreover Execute the command

```
graphics.off()
```

Comment: write this three lines
`graphics.off()`
`par("mar")`
`par(mar=c(1,1,1,1))`

Answer (score 18):

[image]
Just clear the plots and try executing the code again...It worked for me

Comment: Thanks @Shravya Mutyapu, it helped me :)

Answer (score 14):

Just a side-note. Sometimes this "margin" error occurs because you want to **save a high-resolution figure** (eg. `dpi = 300` or `res = 300`) in R.
In this case, what you need to do is to **specify the width and height**. (Btw,  `ggsave()` doesn't require this.)

This **causes** the margin error:

```
# eg. for tiff()
par(mar=c(1,1,1,1))
tiff(filename =  "qq.tiff",
     res = 300,                                                 # the margin error.
     compression = c( "lzw") )
# qq plot for genome wide association study (just an example)
qqman::qq(df$rawp, main = "Q-Q plot of GWAS p-values", cex = .3)
dev.off()
```

This **will fix** the margin error:

```
# eg. for tiff()
par(mar=c(1,1,1,1))
tiff(filename =  "qq.tiff",
     res = 300,                                                 # the margin error.
     width = 5, height = 4, units = 'in',                       # fixed
     compression = c( "lzw") )
# qq plot for genome wide association study (just an example)
qqman::qq(df$rawp, main = "Q-Q plot of GWAS p-values", cex = .3)
dev.off()
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to set margin size by mai=c() in par(), e.g.,

```
par(mfcol=c(5,3),mai=c(0.5,0.5,0.5,0))
```

See the [documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/par.html) for more details about *mai*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just run `graphics.off()` before plotting your data.
This instruction solved my error. So, it's harmless to try it before taking a more complex solution.

Comment: When run from PyCharm with the JetBrains R plugin, this resulted in some sort of infinite recursion and stack overflow: "Error: C stack usage  15924416 is too close to the limit"

Comment: I understand it might not work for all cases. But as I mentioned, before taking any other complex action, it won't be harming you if you try this simple instruction. It worked for my case, and might work for someone else as well.

Comment: It worked for me, Nov 24th, 2021