# How to set up figure limits in barplot?

Tags: r

My code:

```
library(vcd)

barplot(as.matrix(data),ylim=c(0,13),main="P wave",
        xlab="number of clusters", ylab="traveltime rms(ms)",
        col=c("red", "black", "green"), beside=TRUE)

legend("topright", 
       legend = c("fcm","gk","gg"), 
       fill = c( "red", "black", "green"))
```

My data:

```
    5   6   7
fcm 13.0    12.5    11.8
gk  10.9    10.5    10.2
gg  12.0    11.0    10.8
```

I got:

```
Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large
```

What is wrong with ylim?Is there any chance that I can calculate max from data and use it or...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this is of interest for your question?
[Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large, Scatter plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23050928/error-in-plot-new-figure-margins-too-large-scatter-plot)

Try playing around with these parameters:
`par(mar=c(1,1,1,1))`

In anycase, `ylim` is the limit of your axis, not of the margins of the figure. The margins are what is AROUND your plot, and with the axis limit you choose how much information should be on your plot :)

Comment: I have played around with op <- par(mar = c(5,2,2,2) ) but barplot does not appear on the screen!WHY?

Comment: What is the format of your data? How do you import it in R?

Comment: Now it works fine with op <- par(mar=c(5.1,4.1,4.1,2.1))

Answer (score 0):

I've have run this code

```
library(vcd)

fcm <-c(13.0,12.5,11.8)
gk  <-c(10.9 ,   10.5  ,  10.2)
gg  <-c(12.0 ,   11.0 ,   10.8)
data <- rbind(fcm,gk,gg)
colnames(data) <- c(5,6,7)

barplot(as.matrix(data),ylim=c(0,13),main="P wave",
        xlab="number of clusters", ylab="traveltime rms(ms)",
        col=c("red", "black", "green"), beside=TRUE)

legend("topright", 
       legend = c("fcm","gk","gg"), 
       fill = c( "red", "black", "green"))
```

And got this plot. 
[image]

So no problem here. Maybe something you did previously. Have you tried restarting R?

Comment: Yes,I have restarted R.Thanks!