# Error when plotting Naive Bayes Classifier

Tags: r, plot, classification, modeling, naivebayes

I am working on digit recognition on 3 and 8. I have two sets of data, one set of test data and one set of training data. The datasets have the first column "label" which is either 3 or 8 and the other columns are all the different pixels. When I try to find the auc by using the function plot.roc, the error message keeps showing

> Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large

I do not know where is the error. Anyone can spot the mistake here:

```
naive = naiveBayes(label ~., data=trainset, type="raw")
prediction.naive = predict(naive, testset, type = c("raw"))
plot.roc(trainset[,"label"], prediction.naive[,1], col="blue",
     lwd=3, print.auc=TRUE,print.auc.y = 0.3)
```

Comment: Please look at this [Previous SO Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23050928/error-in-plot-new-figure-margins-too-large-scatter-plot)

Comment: Perhaps you are trying to print the raw pixel data.  can you print the two dataframe cols? trainset[,'label'] and predictions.naive[,1]?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large, Scatter plot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23050928/error-in-plot-new-figure-margins-too-large-scatter-plot)