# split.screen into 24 screens lead to error Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large

Tags: r, plot

I have 24 boxplots, each of it comparing an environmental parameter from two different sites. I like to plot them in one figure with 4 plots in the first row, 5 plots in the second row, 5 plots in the third row, 6 plots in the fourth row and 4 plots in the fifth row. This order is of importance, as by this each row contains a set of related parameters, e.g. abiotic parameters like median grain size, sediment porosity, water content etc.

My approach was to use the split.screen function:

```
split.screen(c(4,1)) 
# [1] 1 2 3 4 
split.screen(c(1,4), screen=1) 
# [1] 5 6 7 8
split.screen(c(1,5), screen=2)
# [1] 9 10 11 12 13
split.screen(c(1,5), screen=3)
# [1] 14 15 16 17 18
split.screen(c(1,6), screen=4)
# [1] 19 20 21 22 23 24
split.screen(c(1,4), screen=5)
# [1] 25 26 27 28
```

Then I start to include the plots:

```
screen(5)
boxplot(Data$Parameter1 ~ Data$Sites)
screen(6)
boxplot(Data$Parameter2 ~ Data$Sites)
```

and so on

Until the fourth row it is working, but when I like to add the first plot of the fifth row

```
Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large
```

appears.

I already sized up the plot-window to the maximum on my screen following suggestions from:
[Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12766166/error-in-plot-new-figure-margins-too-large-in-r)

and made the margins smaller following suggestions from:
[Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large, Scatter plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23050928/error-in-plot-new-figure-margins-too-large-scatter-plot)

using

```
par(mar=c(0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1)
```

but nothing worked out. I assume, that the size of my plot-window is to small to display the entire figure (even if I maximise the size). Therefore, I like to ask:

Is there a way to create such a figure without showing it in the plot-window?

Please be aware that I am not an R expert, not familiar with ggplot and not a coder. Therefore, if you have a solution for my problem, please explain it logically comprehensible and like you would explain it to a 9-years-old - that works quite good for me.
Thank you for the effort in advance.

Comment: If you are using Rstudio, it could be that the windows size for plots is very small. You can open an external plotting window by calling `x11()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create figures without using the plot window by using the `png` command, From the doumentation:

```
png(file = "myplot.png", bg = "transparent")
plot(1:10)
rect(1, 5, 3, 7, col = "white")
dev.off()
```

by using the `width` and `height` parameters to `png` you can make very large images. [Here is a link to the documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/png.html)

Comment: I still receive the "figure margins to large"-message. This is how it look like:

Comment: Did you mean to include a link?

Comment: Sorry, just accidentally pressed return and then the message was sent. In the meantime, I solved my issue with your suggestion. It was not necessary for me to draw the rectangle, but thank you for the help

Comment: glad to hear it, the `rect()` command was just part of the example in the documentation that I copied blindly :)

Answer (score 1):

The following code works on my R and RStudio:

```
split.screen(c(4,1)) 
split.screen(c(1,4), screen=1) 
split.screen(c(1,5), screen=2)
split.screen(c(1,5), screen=3)
split.screen(c(1,6), screen=4)
split.screen(c(1,4), screen=5)

for (k in 6:28) {
  screen(k)
  par(mar=c(2,2,0.1,.1), oma=rep(0,4))
  boxplot(iris$Sepal.Length ~ iris$Species)
  text(.35,7.5,k, col="red", pos=4)
}   
close.screen(all=T)
```

[image]