# R: Figure margins too large error when plotting clusters in DBSCAN

Tags: r, plot, dbscan

I'm trying to cluster time series metabolic reaction data to categorize the metabolites using DBSCAN. It's a quite larger data set with 1000 rows (time points) and 2190 variables(metabolite concentration). I'm first trying on a subset of data with 250 rows and 2190 variables. [Here is the distance matrix I used for the clustering.](http://1drv.ms/1Ke8Ikw)

I'm tried to plot the cluster output of the DBSCAN. But I'm getting the bellow error.

> Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large.

Then I tried using the png(). This is the code I used.

```
library(fpc)
dbsEUCLQ1 = dbscan(Q1Matrix,eps=0.6, MinPts = 5, method = "dist")

png(file = "Q1.png", width = 1500, height = 1000)
plot(Q1Data,col=dbsEUCLQ1$cluster)
dev.off
```

But still I'm not able to generate the plot. I'm getting the below error.

> > plot(Q1Data,col=dbsEUCLQ1$cluster) Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large
> >     dev.off function (which = dev.cur())  {
> >         if (which == 1) 
> >             stop("cannot shut down device 1 (the null device)")
> >         .External(C_devoff, as.integer(which))
> >         dev.cur() }

Am I doing something wrong here? Any help regarding this is appreciated.

Comment: try reading this for your answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12766166/error-in-plot-new-figure-margins-too-large-in-r/17220137#17220137

Answer (score 0):

Here is a relevant answer from a very similar question:

> I had this error when I was trying to plot high dimensional data. If that's what is going on with you, try multidimensional scaling: http://www.statmethods.net/advstats/mds.html

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17220137/338303