# Plotting coda mcmc objects giving error in plot.new

Tags: r

I have an R package I am working on that returns output from a Metropolis-Hastings sampler. The output consists of, among other things, matrices where the columns are the variables and the rows are the samples from the posterior. I convert these into `coda` `mcmc` objects with this code:

```
colnames(results$beta) = x$data$Pops
results$beta = mcmc(results$beta, thin = thin)
```

where `thin` is 183 and `beta` is a 21 x 15 matrix (this is a toy example). The `mcmc.summary` method works fine, but the `plot.mcmc` gives me:

```
Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large
```

I have done a bit of debugging. All the values are finite, there are no `NA`'s, the limits of the axes seem to be being set okay, and there are enough panels (2 plots each with 4 rows and 2 columns) I think. Is there something I am missing in the coercion into the `mcmc` object?

Package source and all associated files can be found on http://github.com/jmcurran/rbayesfst. A script which will produce the error quickly is in the unexported function `mytest`, so you'll need

```
rbayesfst:::mytest()
```

to get it to run.

There has been suggestion that this has been answered already in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12766166) question, but I would like to point out that it is not me setting any of the `par` values, but `plot.mcmc` so my question is not about `par` or `plot` but what (if anything) I am doing wrong in making a matrix into an `mcmc` object that cannot be plotted by `plot.mcmc` It can't be the size of the matrix, because I have had examples with many more dimensions directly from `rjags` that worked fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12766166/error-in-plot-new-figure-margins-too-large-in-r)

Comment: If the function is unexported, you'll need `:::`. Also, if you're plotting many panels in one figure, you'll need to create a large enough graphics device for things to actually fit in there. This is where the margins error comes from. (I can't install your package because of compilation errors.)

Comment: I have corrected the `:::` and also added a saved file of results to github repository in the `inst/extdata` directory called `r.Rda` which can be restored using the `load` function. This will give you an output object with a sample from the posterior of size 2000.