# How to adjust the position of circles when plotting venn diagram

Tags: r, plot, venn-diagram

I wanted to plot the venn diagram with two sets in which one set falls completely within another. I could draw a diagram with R package `Venndiagram` like this

[image]

```
library(VennDiagram)
grid.newpage();
venn.plot <- draw.pairwise.venn(area1 =467 ,area2 =273 ,cross.area = 273,
category = c("Set1", "Set2"),fill = c("darkorange", "dodgerblue1"),
lty = rep("solid", 2),lwd = c(2,2),col = c("black","black"),cex = 2,cat.cex = 2,cat.pos = c(310, 135),
cat.dist = 0.09,cat.just = list(c(-1, -1), c(1, 1)),
ext.pos = 30,ext.dist = -0.05,
ext.length = 0.85,ext.line.lwd = 2,ext.line.lty = "dashed");
grid.draw(venn.plot);
```

This may sound like esoteric tricks, but how to adjust the position of the circles, say, instead of two concentric circles, let the inner circle touch the the outer one?

Something like [this one here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fqwE.png). I added one non overlapping element.

I could not find an argument in the `Venndiagram` package allowing me to adjust the position of the circles.

Comment: It does not make much sense since one contains the other. Here are few examples you could look at: https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/13301_6641d73cfac741a59c0a851feb99e98b.html and http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/6401_7582b217798044d3ae87ebbdc47b7562.html

Comment: @lizzie. Thank you for your comment, yes, I checked the web you suggested, but still could not find any argument to adjust the position of the circles. I could cheat by add a non overlapping element like the example I added in the post, but...

Answer (score 1):

You can try this with `plotrix`:

```
library(plotrix)
area1 = 467 
area2 = 273
r1 = round(sqrt(area1/pi))
r2 = round(sqrt(area2/pi))
xc = 8
yc = 8
plot(0:40,0:40,type="n",xlab="",ylab="",main="Venn Diagram", xaxt='n', yaxt='n')
draw.circle(xc+r1,yc+r1,r1,border="black", col="orange",lty=1,lwd=1)
draw.circle(xc+2*r1-r2,yc+r1,r2,border="black", col="steelblue",lty=1,lwd=1)
text(xc+2*r1-r2,yc+r1, '272', cex=3)  
text(xc+(r1-r2)/2+1,yc+r1, '195', cex=3) 
text(xc+r1,yc+2*r1+7, 'Set1', cex=3) 
text(xc+r1+r2,1, 'Set2', cex=3)
```

[image]

Comment: Actually there is a typo in the text, it should be 273 instead of 272.

Comment: yes, It works! TKS! The solution is much more complicated than I expected... PS: there is one little bump    plot(0:40,0:40,type="n",xlab="",ylab="",main="Venn Diagram", xaxt='n', yaxt='n')
Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large

Comment: but can be easily solved by the solution suggested [here]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12766166/error-in-plot-new-figure-margins-too-large-in-r

Comment: "Actually there is a typo in the text, it should be 273 instead of 272." that is all right, this is just an example, TKS very much!

Comment: @Sandipian Dey, I would very much like to up vote your answer, but could not since my reputation is lower than 15, which is minimal for up voting. By "update the answer", but do you mean by that? You really solve my issue, so very happy to do any thing if that helps you.