# How to adjust margins of a heatmap?

Tags: r, heatmap, margins

I need to adjust the margins of my heatmap (especially at top and left).

I already kicked out color keys and headline, since they used most of my space. But now I'm left with blank space. I don't need that at top/left of my picture. I was using `heatmap2`. I used a margin within the heatmap2 and a par-margin before the picture. But I'm not sure, how those interact. Furthermore I save my picture in svg and define weight/height here as well.

```
svg("mypic.svg", width=20, height=16)
par(mar=c(1,10,0.1,10))
heatmap.2(mat_data_round,
          key = F,
          cellnote = note,     
          notecol="black",      
          density.info="none",  
          trace="none",         
          margins =c(7,14),     
          col=colfun,          
          dendrogram="row",    
          Colv="NA",           
          cexRow=2,
          cexCol=2)
```

What I expect is to not show white/blank space.

[image: Heatmap]

**Source**

The code is (mainly) inspired by

https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datei:Gdp_to_debt_ratio.svg

I try to adjust and update things like this.

**Solution**
There was a small clash with the proposed solution. I had to remove `main` in order to make it work. The following code drops the dendrogram feature, which is fine. Row and Column labels are readable with predefined width and height of my final svg. Thank you very much

```
svg("myheatmap.svg", width=20, height=16)
heatmap.2(mat_data_round,
          key = F,
          dendrogram = "none",
          trace = "none",
          cellnote = note,
          notecol="black",  
          col=colfun,  
          Colv="NA",  
          lwid = c(0.2,5),
          lhei = c(0.2,5),
          margins =c(7,14),
          cexRow=2,
          cexCol=2)
```

Comment: do you need to keep a dendrogram?

Comment: The dendrogram roots are not essential for the picture. They can be squeered or deleted (if helpful).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specifiy the margins with the `lhei` and `lwid` arguments. With `lhei` you pass the margin size below and above and with `lwid` to the right and to the left.

More precise:
Your layout is a matrix of 4 cells: 1. heatmap, 2. key, 3. row dendrogram, 4. column dendrogram. With `lhei`you can specify the size of both rows and with `lwid` the size of both columns.

```
library(gplots)

data(mtcars)
x  <- as.matrix(mtcars)

lwid=c(0.2,5) #make column of dendrogram and key very small and other colum very big 
lhei=c(0.2,5) #make row of key and other dendrogram very small and other row big. 

heatmap.2(x,
          key = F,
          dendrogram = "none",
          trace = "none",
          lwid = lwid,
          lhei = lhei)
```

[image]

Comment: That's perfect :) Next time I will make use of mtcar data as MWE.

Comment: I have another issue. The `heatmap.2` looks perfect, but I can no longer save the image? It says "figure margins too large".

Comment: That's weird.. I obviously could save it since you see in in the answer and we didn't change the margins actually. Try `dev.off()` to reset your margin settings

Comment: `dev.off()` doesn't help. I tried your mtcars code, it's working. There is still another clash with my initial settings. I try different combinations with `margins =c(7,14)` etc.

Comment: this is a common problem. You'll find dozens of questions on SO. You'll find a solution. Check here e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12766166/error-in-plot-new-figure-margins-too-large-in-r/32216195