# for loop for analysis of many files

Tags: r, function, loops, for-loop

I am trying to write an R script using for loop to perform statistical analyses and to produce plots for each file.

my files ends with .txt
Here is my script but it requires improvement as below.

```
files <- list.files(path="/Users/MD/Desktop/Files/", pattern="*.txt")
for (i in files){
  i_automean <- mean(i[1:5651,10])
  i_xmean <- mean(i[5652:7977,10])
  barplot(i[,10]/i_automean, ylim = c(0,2.5))
  abline(h=1, col ="red", lwd =3)
  abline(h=22.06126/i_automean, col ="red", lwd =3)
  abline(v=2300*1.2, col="blue", lwd =3)
  abline(v=5651*1.2, col="blue", lwd=3)
  pdf(i.pdf, "/Users/MD/Desktop/Files/");
  dev.off()
} 

Error in i[1:5651, 10] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

When I run each command one by one for each file,  I don't receive error:

Commands that I run one by one are:

```
File1 <- read.table(file = "/Users/MD/Desktop/Files/File1.txt")
File1
File1_automean <- mean(File1[1:5651,10])
File1_automean
File1_Xmean <- mean(File1[5652:7977,10])
File1_Xmean
barplot(File1[,10]/18.02876, ylim = c(0,2.5))
abline(h=1, col ="red", lwd =3)
abline(h=22.06126/18.02876, col ="red", lwd =3)
abline(v=2300*1.2, col="blue", lwd =3)
abline(v=5651*1.2, col="blue", lwd=3)
```

Note: 18.02876 is File1_automean result.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but I think you forget to load the file in your first chunk of code, you should add `i = read.table(file = i)` before `automean` part. For now, i is a character vector. But, if load your file as `i`, I bet you will have some issues with the naming part at the end.

Comment: I add an answer with a proposed revision of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you think about this solution ?

```r
files <- list.files(path="/Users/MD/Desktop/Files/", pattern="*.txt")
setwd("/Users/MD/Desktop/Files")
for (j in 1:length(files)){
  i <- read.table(files[j])
  i_automean <- mean(i[1:5651,10])
  i_xmean <- mean(i[5652:7977,10])
  barplot(i[,10]/i_automean, ylim = c(0,2.5))
  abline(h=1, col ="red", lwd =3)
  abline(h=22.06126/i_automean, col ="red", lwd =3)
  abline(v=2300*1.2, col="blue", lwd =3)
  abline(v=5651*1.2, col="blue", lwd=3)
  pdf(paste0(files[j],".pdf"))
  graphics.off()
}
```

Comment: One thing I need is to open pdf files and reduce their size, because it says figure margins are too big. Pdf files can't open.

Comment: @user12367991, in the Rstudio console, try to run `dev.off` several times (it will force to reset the graphic device in rstudio (https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200488548-Problem-with-Plots-or-Graphics-Device). I will also edit my code to use `graphics.off()` instead which is (I think) more appropriate for running script. Otherwise, it can be dependent of Rstudio, maybe you can try to run this script directly in R terminal. More discussion here: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12766166/error-in-plot-new-figure-margins-too-large-in-r)