# Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large doing a Histogram

Tags: r, plot, histogram

I was trying to do a histogram with the line of density and this error keeps appearing. I don't know how to correct it, someone could help?
Here is my code:

```
hist(x1,col="peachpuff",border="black",prob = TRUE,xlab = "x1",main = "im")
lines(density(x1),lwd = 2,col = "chocolate3")
```

Comment: See here <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12766166/error-in-plot-new-figure-margins-too-large-in-r>

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.