# ROC graph wont work due to Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large

Tags: r, regression, logistic-regression, roc

I am trying to make a ROC graph I am new to R so this may be an easy question but, for some reason, it won't let me create this graph and keeps saying this

```
Setting levels: control = 0, case = 1

Setting direction: controls < cases 

Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large
```

I have installed the library(pROC) and have this code

```
probability = predict(logfit, AllTeamTotal, type = "response")

prediction[probability>0.5] = 1 table(prediction, AllTeamTotal$upset) 
ROC <- roc(AllTeamTotal$upset ~ prediction, plot = TRUE, print.auc = TRUE)
```

Comment: Try dragging your plotting window to make it larger and running the code again. You can also try `par(mar = c(0, 0, 0, 0))` and repeating the code

Comment: How are you using R? Command line, Rstudio, Mac, Windows, Linux?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12766166/error-in-plot-new-figure-margins-too-large-in-r)